# Bundle Id format

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, app-store-connect

As in Apple documentation the bundle Id should be in com.companyName.appName format .My friend while filling details in iTunes ,write the bundle id as XZCSDF.com.companyName.appName may be because the App Id is in this format.I tried using the same bundle in Project plist as "XZCSDF.com.companyName.appName".Everything is fine,while in the final step of uploading the binary it gives error.There is no edit option for BundleId in iTunes ,so i only modified it.Does this format okay or we need to fill all the details again by deleting the App in iTunes and creating again.

Answer (score 0):

The bundle ID in your project/Info.plist should not include the prefix (XZCSDF). In iTunes connect, you choose the app ID from a dropdown so that must be correct.

Comment: if i remove XZCSDF from plist bundle Id ,it doesn't identify profile then.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to delete the app from iTunes Connect and try again with the correct format.

Comment: Yeah..thinking to do the same jmstone